# Why do I get the error "use of deleted function 'class : : class()"

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
protected:
    string name;
    int roll;
    int age;
public:
    student(string n, int r, int a)
    {
        name = n;
        roll = r;
        age = a;
    }
};

class test : public student
{
protected:
    int sub[5];
public:
    void marks()
    {
        cout << "Enter marks in 5 subjects: " << endl;
        cin >> sub[0] >> sub[1] >> sub[2] >> sub[3] >> sub[4];
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout << "Name : " << name << "\nRoll number : " << roll << "\nAge: " << age << endl;
        cout << "Marks in 5 subjects : " << sub[0] << ", " << sub[1] << ", " << sub[2] << ", " << sub[3] << ", " << sub[4] << endl;
    }
};

class sports
{
protected:
    int sportmarks;
public:
    sports(int sm)
    {
        sportmarks = sm;
    }
};

class result : public test, public sports
{
    int tot;
    float perc;
public:
    void calc()
    {
        tot = sportmarks;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            tot = tot + sub[i];
        perc = (tot / 600.0) * 100;
        cout << "Total: " << tot << "\nPercentage: " << perc << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    student ob1("Name", 781, 19);
    sports ob2(78);
    result ob;
    ob.marks();
    ob.display();
    ob.calc();
}
```

I've been asked to use parameterized constructors to do this problem and notice I get these errors when I use constructors. Sorry if this post is inconvenient to read. In what way can I run this code while creating objects from parameterized constructors?

```
use of deleted function 'result::result()'
use of deleted function 'test::test()'.
no matching function for call to 'student::student()'
no matching function for call to 'sports::sports()'
```

Comment: In your `main()`, there is `result ob;`. That's a request of default construction. `class result` has no constructor at all. In this case, the compiler kindly generates a default constructor for you. It's build calling the default constructor of all base classes and all members. So, here we are.

Comment: FYI: [Implicitly-declared default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Implicitly-declared_default_constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`student` and `sports` have user-defined constructors, so the compiler does not generate default constructors for them.

`test` and `result` have no user-defined constructors, so the compiler will generate default constructors for them. However, since `student` and `sports` have no default constructors, the generated default constructors are marked `delete`'d as they are not usable. That is why you get errors.

To make your `main()` compile as-is, you need to define your own default constructors for `test` and `result` which pass explicit parameter values to their base classes, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
protected:
    string name;
    int roll;
    int age;
public:
    student(string n, int r, int a)
    {
        name = n;
        roll = r;
        age = a;
    }
};

class test : public student
{
protected:
    int sub[5];
public:
    test() : student("", 0, 0) {}

    void marks()
    {
        cout << "Enter marks in 5 subjects: " << endl;
        cin >> sub[0] >> sub[1] >> sub[2] >> sub[3] >> sub[4];
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << "Name : " << name << "\nRoll number : " << roll << "\nAge: " << age << endl;
        cout << "Marks in 5 subjects : " << sub[0] << ", " << sub[1] << ", " << sub[2] << ", " << sub[3] << ", " << sub[4] << endl;
    }
};

class sports
{
protected:
    int sportmarks;
public:
    sports(int sm)
    {
        sportmarks = sm;
    }
};

class result : public test, public sports
{
    int tot;
    float perc;
public:
    result() : test(), sports(0) {}

    void calc()
    {
        tot = sportmarks;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            tot = tot + sub[i];
        perc = (tot / 600.0) * 100;
        cout << "Total: " << tot << "\nPercentage: " << perc << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    student ob1("Name", 781, 19);
    sports ob2(78);
    result ob;
    ob.marks();
    ob.display();
    ob.calc();
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/CjJEQr)

However, this is not very useful, so I would suggest tweaking `result`'s constructor to take the `student` and `sports` objects you have already created beforehand, and pass them to the base class copy constructors, which the compiler will generate for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class student
{
protected:
    string name;
    int roll;
    int age;
public:
    student(string n, int r, int a)
    {
        name = n;
        roll = r;
        age = a;
    }
};

class test : public student
{
protected:
    int sub[5];
public:
    test(const student &s) : student(s) {}

    void marks()
    {
        cout << "Enter marks in 5 subjects: " << endl;
        cin >> sub[0] >> sub[1] >> sub[2] >> sub[3] >> sub[4];
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << "Name : " << name << "\nRoll number : " << roll << "\nAge: " << age << endl;
        cout << "Marks in 5 subjects : " << sub[0] << ", " << sub[1] << ", " << sub[2] << ", " << sub[3] << ", " << sub[4] << endl;
    }
};

class sports
{
protected:
    int sportmarks;
public:
    sports(int sm)
    {
        sportmarks = sm;
    }
};

class result : public test, public sports
{
    int tot;
    float perc;
public:
    result(const student &s, const sports &sp) : test(s), sports(sp) {}

    void calc()
    {
        tot = sportmarks;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            tot = tot + sub[i];
        perc = (tot / 600.0) * 100;
        cout << "Total: " << tot << "\nPercentage: " << perc << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    student ob1("Name", 781, 19);
    sports ob2(78);
    result ob(ob1, ob2);
    ob.marks();
    ob.display();
    ob.calc();
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/7sa7Pn)

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now. I did not know you could pass them like that. Can I still ask when we get the error "no matching function for call to" ?

Comment: @Aniki I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear about it. I meant, what is the reason/condition behind getting the "no matching function" error. But I think I get it now. Thank you. And sorry for the extra comments.